How to error handle Supabase expired auth email in Next.js?
I'm trying to handle an error when the user clicks on an expired auth confirmation URL from supabase. I would like to put a banner saying that the link from the email was expired or give the option for the user to resend an email confirmation
This is the url I am redirected to:
http://localhost:3000/?error=access_denied&error_code=403&error_description=Email+link+is+invalid+or+has+expired#error=access_denied&error_code=403&error_description=Email+link+is+invalid+or+has+expired
When I look at the supabase docs it shows me this snippet of code to do so.
const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.hash.slice())

if (params.get('error_code').startsWith('4')) {
  // show error message if error is a 4xx error
  window.alert(params.get('error_description'))
}


I've read that you can only get url query strings on client components but I think it would be better if the confirmation page (homepage) is SSR. Is there a way to use both SSR and get this URL param?
I've tried to use useSearchParams but wondering if there is a better method
